# How to check status of error code in csh?

Tags: linux, unix, status, csh

This is not a Perl questions, this is a csh question.

Perl 5.8.8 on Linux RHEL 5.5.56.

I have a test Perl program which uses 'exit 3;' to set the exit status. The Perl program is run from a csh script I call 'test'.

Perl program:

```
#/usr/bin/perl
# July 11, 2014
# Test exit code with csh $status variable
my($i);
$i=3;
print "$0 Exit with error code $i\n";
exit $i;
```

'test' csh script that calls Perl progam:

```
#/bin/csh
# July 10, 2014,

perl tstatus.pl
echo "Status=$status"
if ($status > 0) then
    echo "ERROR in status: $status"
endif
```

The line 'echo "ERROR in status: $status" is never executed even though 'echo "Status=$status' says status is 3.

How do I get my csh to check and act on the value of $status?
$status is a system variable it seems.

I have also tried 'if ($stats) then' but that doesn't work either. No errors are reported in the csh script.

Thank you.

p.s. I don't do complicated stuff in csh so I'm not ready to go to bash yet. I've read the "why not csh" file already. Thanks.

Comment: You've read "why not csh". But have you understood it?

Comment: Your echo call sets it's own status, the echo call always works, so your if condition never triggers.

Comment: Doh! Of course. That makes total sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `echo` command succeeds, resetting `$status` to 0.  Thus `if` never sees nonzero `$status`.

Therefore the solution is to either eliminate the `echo` command or save the value of `$status` immediately after the `perl` command.

I recently encountered [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775689/cannot-set-tcsh-exit-status-using-a-variable/39775698#39775698) myself.

Answer (score 1):

every line executed in csh sets $status

I usually follow any statement, where I want to test the status with something like:

set myrc = $status

which will persist regardless of the number of statements that are executed in between call and the evaluation of the result.

eg:

```
    perl tstatus.pl
    set myrc = $status
    echo "Status=$myrc"
    if ($myrc> 0) then
        echo "ERROR in status: $myrc"
    endif
```