# Cannot set tcsh exit status using a variable

Tags: csh, tcsh

I usually use bash, but in this case I must use tcsh.  To my surprise, I cannot use a variable containing the exit status as the argument to `exit`:

```
[bash] tcsh
[tcsh] set status=2
[tcsh] echo $status
2
[tcsh] exit $status
exit
[bash] echo $?
0
```

A literal argument to `exit` does work as expected:

```
[bash] tcsh
[tcsh] exit 2
exit
[bash] echo $?
2
```

What on earth is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$status` is a built-in C shell variable containing the exit status of the previous command.  Try echoing `$status` twice and you can see that tcsh changes the value of `$status` to 0, the exit status of the first `echo` command:

```
[bash] tcsh
[tcsh] set status=2
[tcsh] echo $status
2
[tcsh] echo $status
0
```

The solution is to merely use a different variable name that is not a C shell built-in variable:

```
[bash] tcsh
[tcsh] set result=2
[tcsh] echo $result
2
[tcsh] exit $result
exit
[bash] echo $?
2
```